# Black artifacts on plane with procedural displacement

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying out the procedural displacement in 2.8 with Cycles following [this](https://youtu.be/yrMee2gcS20) tutorial. The object has 100 subdivisions in addition to a SubSurf modifier, and one material with two shaders separated to form rocks and some water. When rendering with 4 levels of subdivisions, there are these black marks all over the water.

[image: Render with 4 Subdivisions]

When I render with only 3 subdivisions, there are fewer artifacts.

[image]

Shouldn't more subdivisons give a more realistic render?
[.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ravh1ldwv3ylm81/landscape3.blend?dl=0)

Comment: It would help if you could use drop box to upload the file. I cannot download it from your link. It looks like you need to set more render passes.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan What do you mean by render passes?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but those are not artifacts. The person in the tutorial used procedural displacement to create "waves" in the water by adding a noise texture to displace the water surface, then stretching it in one direction. If you look closely, the black marks are actually parts of the waves.

Take a look at the noise texture you used to create this effect and make sure it is scaled properly. This also makes sense because displacing a more high-res geometry just results in more intricate details like you have noticed.

A little advice for later on: when following a tutorial, don't just try to copy everything. That will get you a result, but in the end, you have learned nothing. Try to understand what the person is doing. This will teach you a lot, and will also make it easier to find and solve mistakes.